# Is there a way for a consumer to stop listening to a topic by just using config/properties file?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

Is there a way we can put in the properties/config file to stop a consumer from listening to a topic? I just want to know whether I can have an option that I can just simply like "Turn on/off" Kafka without having to build and deploy my project.

Comment: Do you create `Kafka` consumer using `@KafkaListener`? Its better if you can provide your current working code your `Kafka` consumer.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear how you plan on changing a property file at runtime.

But yes, let's say you have some trigger action (for example, an HTTP method) that sets a boolean, then you can stop the consumer loop

```
private AtomicBoolean running = ... ; // set from some property


// in some thread/method
ConsumerRecords records;
while (running.get()) {  // consumer will stop if the field is updated
   records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
}
```

In `spring-kafka`, you should be able to call `.stop()` on the listener container... I'm not familiar with cloud-streams functions